# Tomcat 8 Unable to compile class for JSP when testing Websockets

Tags: maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, websocket

I made Websockets server with `javax.websocket` (Maven, Tomcat 8). And I want to test it. So I made JUnit test class where I start new Tomcat instance. But when I run test, I get

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/feeds] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP] with root cause

It seems to me I'm missing some libraries or implementation classes. Googling and search on stackoverflow forced me to check Tomcat version, but than did'n solve the issue

Here is my pom.xml dependencies section:

```
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.37</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.63</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.63</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.63</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-impl-base</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is WSserver code:

```
package xyz.maksimenko.feedsreader;

import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import xyz.maksimenko.feedsreader.feedobject.Feed;
import xyz.maksimenko.util.DAOfactory;

import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnError;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;

@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/feeds")
public class WebSocketServer {

    @Inject
    private WSSessionHandler sessionHandler;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session){
        System.out.println("User connected " + session.getRequestURI());
        sessionHandler.addSession(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(String message, Session session){
        try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(message))){
            JsonObject jsonMessage = reader.readObject();

            String action = jsonMessage.getString("action");
            switch(action) {
            case "login":
                String login = jsonMessage.getString("login");
                //TODO validate login input
                sessionHandler.userLogged(session, login);
                break;
            case "feeds": //get feeds for category
                //TODO get category
                String categoryName = jsonMessage.getString("category");
                sessionHandler.feedsRequested(session, categoryName);
                break;
            case "items": //get items for feed
                String feedName = jsonMessage.getString("feed");
                sessionHandler.itemsRequested(session, feedName);
                break;
            case "all_items": //get items for all feeds
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session){
        sessionHandler.removeSession(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable error){
        //Logger.getLogger(DeviceWebSocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, error);
    }

}
```

And here is test class:

```
   package xyz.maksimenko.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.json.spi.JsonProvider;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

@ClientEndpoint
public class WebSocketsTest extends Assert implements Runnable{

    private Tomcat mTomcat;
    private Thread serverThread;
    //private String mWorkingDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

    private final String WSURI = "ws://localhost:9999/feeds/";
    private final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/feeds";
    private final String TEST_CATEGORY_NAME = "IT";
    private Session session;
    private String receivedMessage;

    @Before
    public void setupAndStartServer() throws Throwable {
        mTomcat = new Tomcat();
        mTomcat.setPort(9999);
        mTomcat.addWebapp(CONTEXT_PATH, new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath());
        serverThread = new Thread(this);
        serverThread.start();
        connectToServer();
    }


    @After
    public void stopServer() {
        try {
            mTomcat.stop();
            mTomcat.destroy();
            deleteDirectory(new File("target/tomcat/"));
        } catch (LifecycleException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void deleteDirectory(File path) {
        if(path == null) return;
        if(path.exists()) {
            Arrays.asList(path.listFiles()).stream().forEach(file -> { if(file.isDirectory()) deleteDirectory(file); file.delete(); });
            path.delete();
        }
    }

    private void connectToServer(){
        try {
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            container.connectToServer(this, new URI(WSURI));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @OnOpen
    private void onOpen(Session session){
        this.session = session;
    }

    @OnMessage
    private void onMessage(String message){
        receivedMessage = message;
    }

    @OnClose
    private void onClose(Session session){

    }

    @Test
    public void login(){
        boolean timeout = false;
        final short timeoutInterval = 32767;
        short counter = 0;
        JsonProvider provider = JsonProvider.provider();
        JsonObject json = provider.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("action", "login")
                .add("login", "testuser01@mail.ru")
                .build();
        session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(json.toString());
        while(receivedMessage == null){
            if(++counter == timeoutInterval) {
                timeout = true; 
                break;
            }
        }

        assertFalse(timeout);

        try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(receivedMessage))){
            JsonObject jsonMessage = reader.readObject();
            String action = jsonMessage.getString("action");
            assertTrue(action.equals("categories"));

            JsonArray categoriesJson = jsonMessage.getJsonArray("set");
            JsonObject firstCategory = categoriesJson.getJsonObject(0);
            assertTrue(firstCategory.getString("title").equals(TEST_CATEGORY_NAME));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mTomcat.start();
        } catch (LifecycleException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        mTomcat.getServer().await();
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is complete stack trace on exception:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/feeds] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:87)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.PageInfo.<init>(PageInfo.java:79)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Dependencies with `<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>` (e.g.  `tomcat-embed-core`) seem to specify version 7.0.63! Try 8.0.28.

Comment: Forgot to tell, tried 8.0.26 here. Just tried 8.0.28, but didn't help

Comment: what's the `root cause` of your error? can you include the complete stack trace?

Comment: Added full stack trace